# String-based cursor positioning

Tags: java, textarea, awt, stringbuffer

How do I locate the cursor position in a Java textarea where the text is held in a StringBuffer? I am trying to implement the backspace function in a text editor. The API lists how to set data. I need to get the cursor position, to know at which character position the cursor is, not the onscreen global coordinates of the cursor.

Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you managing the text, i.e. how are the JTextArea and the StringBuffer connected and updated? Are you subclassing AbstractDocument/AbstractDocument.Content?  Can you show us the code?

Comment: I am not using a JTextArea. That was just to give context to my question. The UI of the editor is extended from a JFrame. How do I present the code? I would say it is rather long for this edit pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write [`KeyListeners`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/KeyListenerandKeyEvent.htm) for keypress events in the `TextArea` and keep a virtual cursor of where you are in the `TextArea`. Then map that offset into your `StringBuffer`, there is no magic way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Jarrod Roberson

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Swing [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html), use [`JTextArea.getCaretPosition()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29).

If you are using an AWT [`TextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html), see Jarrod Roberson's answer.

Comment: UI programming (and programming for that matter) is still new to me and I had not even thought to consider Swing or AWT. I was just told it would be beneficial to learn through doing, and presented a bare-bones hand-coded UI to try and tackle. Thanks for the input. It lights my way.

Comment: Swing is more complex to learn, but more flexible and powerful than AWT.  You might find [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/grid/library/os-swingswt/) comparing AWT, Swing, and SWT useful.

Comment: You've inconvenienced yourself on my behalf. I am sincerely grateful, Kevin K.